# extra XML data key value pairs to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Here is the XML I am trying to extract from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<dictionary>
<item>
<key><string>MemberNumber</string></key>
<value><string>66962336209</string></value>
</item></dictionary>
```

Create table #1 (ID int identity(1,1), extradata xml)

```
INSERT INTO #1
Select '<dictionary><item><key><string>MemberNumber</string></key><value><string>66962336209</string></value></item></dictionary>'


SELECT extradata.value('/*:dictionary[1]/*:Item[1]/*:Key[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM #1;

select
    a.c.value('*:Value[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [value]
from #1 as t
    outer apply t.extradata.nodes('
        *:dictionary/*:Item[*:Key="code"]'
    ) as a(c)
```

I keep getting NULL values back.

I want to get the key value pairs on two different rows, I can transform the data from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL code is using a wildcard namespace though your sample XML doesn't have any. Also, the XPath expressions are completely off.
Please try the following:

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<dictionary>
    <item>
        <key>
            <string>MemberNumber</string>
        </key>
        <value>
            <string>66962336209</string>
        </value>
    </item>
</dictionary>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , col.value('(value/string/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS [value]
FROM @tbl tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[xml_data].nodes('/dictionary/item[key/string/text() = "MemberNumber"]') AS tab(col);
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID |    value    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 66962336209 |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: If I get the OP correctly, he wants to get the key and the value in two columns. So `.nodes()` just down to `/dictionary/item` and then the `.value()` for both... Might be I got this wrong...

Comment: @Shnugo, let's wait for the response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that helped. New to xml extraction, was putting together code from diff sources. Added the key name as well to it.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<dictionary>
    <item>
        <key>
            <string>MemberNumber</string>
        </key>
        <value>
            <string>66962336209</string>
        </value>
    </item>
</dictionary>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , col.value('(key/string/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS [key]
    , col.value('(value/string/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS [value]
FROM @tbl tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[xml_data].nodes('/dictionary/item[key/string/text() = "MemberNumber"]') AS tab(col);
```

Comment: It is called shredding, i.e. conversion from the XML data type to relational data set.

Comment: This was a good approach, if you wanted to return various `<item>` nodes as a derived set. In this case I'd return the names and the values as a typical *key-value-pair*, and use standard SQL approaches to filter this set. But it looks as if you are reading one value for a given name. it should be faster to do this without the need of `.nodes()`...

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to place an alternative:

(Credits to Yitzhak Khabinsky for the MCVE  - +1 from my side):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<dictionary>
    <item>
        <key>
            <string>MemberNumber</string>
        </key>
        <value>
            <string>66962336209</string>
        </value>
    </item>
</dictionary>');
```

--We can use an external variable to get this more generic

```
DECLARE @KeyName VARCHAR(100)='MemberNumber';
```

--The query

```sql
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.xml_data.value('(/dictionary
                          /item[key/string/text()=sql:variable("@KeyName")] 
                          /value
                          /string
                          /text())[1]','varchar(30)')
FROM @tbl t
--This WHERE is not mandatory, but it might speed things up 
--(if there are many items and many rows without this key)
WHERE t.xml_data.exist('/dictionary[item/key/string/text()=sql:variable("@KeyName")]')=1;
```

The idea in short:

- We declare the key-name we are looking for. This allows to use a variable to get the apprach mor generic.
- The `WHERE`-clause is calling `.exist()`. Try it out. You don't need this, but it might gain some speed (depending on your data).
- The `.value()` function is stepping down to `/dictionary/item`, but uses the predicate to filter for the one `<item>`, where there is a key with the given name. Using this `<item>` we step deeper into `<value>` and read its content.